the Shannon entropy of a radar matrix
Now,I have a 2D radar spectrum data,which is obtained from 2D FFT along fast time and angle dimension at one range and azimuth coordinate points and its neighbor several different range and azimuth coordinate points, whose row represents range information and column denotes azimuth information. I need to calculate the Shannon entropy about this 2D-matrix according its power distribute.But,the entropy values are the same at different but similar coordinate points. Why does this phenomenon occur?What should I do for this case?
The code is shown：
Pro = Data/sum(sum(Data));
Pro(find(Pro<10eps)) = []; %
entro = -sum(sum(Pro . log2(Pro)));
where,Data is the 2D matrix;entro is the calculated entropy.

Maybe more appropriate at https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/ ?
